# hyperbolic metrics

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Let $D_1\subset D_2$ be simply connected domains in the complex plane. Let $\lambda_1$ and
$\lambda_2$ be the corresponding hyperbolic (Poincare) metrics. It seems intuitive to me that
$\lambda_2$ is greater than or equal to $\lambda_1$, but I cannot prove it. Can someone offer a quick proof or a reference?

Comment: What is your order relation on metrics? If you say one metric is less than another if and only if one domain is contained in another, then I have a proof.

Comment: This is true essentially by the Schwarz lemma. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma

Comment: @DanGallo could you answer Ryan's request? it's maybe standard language for you and and Sam Nead, but not everybody.

Comment: YCor- I am not familiar with order relations on metrics.

Comment: YCor- My question is just whether the distance between two points in one metric is greater than or equal to the distance between the same two points in the other metric.

Comment: @DanGallo: thank you. If you say "greater than", it means that you have an order relation in mind, which you finally answered (I didn't guess the order because "metric" can refer both to the Riemannian 2-tensor and to the distance it determines)

Answer (score 3):

As Ian says, this is answered by the Schwarz lemma. The precise statement you want is due to Ahlfors - here is the Wikipedia page for the [Ahlfors-Schwarz-Pick lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Ahlfors%E2%80%93Pick_theorem).